# Scroll-down page with changing URL

Tags: javascript

I've noticed this Popular Science page that dynamically loads the content when scrolling down: http://www.popsci.com/HTC-Oculus-Competitor-Valve-Vive

How do they do this? Ok, it's not hard to load extra content at the bottom of the page when user has scrolled to certain point. But this page changes the URL of the page, and there is no visible reloading/reflowing of the page.

Comment: Wow, 4 downvotes, what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are using the HTML5 History API to achieve that. Mainly `pushState`, `popState` and `replaceState` functions of the `history` object.

Mark Pilgrim has wrote a very good introduction to the History API in his website: http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history